# Jest testing fails on double colon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, ecmascript-next

Trying to test React app with Jest. Getting errors when run my code:

```
 FAIL  src\App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    C:/Users/user1/Projects/map-editor/src/App.js: Unexpected token (40:33)
        38 |         <div className="Main-content">
        39 |           <Sidebar
      > 40 |             parentOnCreatePoint={::this.handleSidebarCreateCallback}
           |                                  ^
        41 |             parentOnChangePoint={::this.handleSidebarChangeCallback}
```

My webpack config for bable looks like this:

```
plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-0','stage-2'],
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Read [here for more info on the `::` operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator). I'll add that it is an ***extremely*** bad idea to bind your callbacks inside a react render method like this. It means you create a new method each render and react can't optimise because the props are changing.

Comment: @caesay Ok, thank you. Haven't know about it, changed to standart .bind(this).

Comment: you miss the point, you shouldn't use `.bind(` in react props like this. you should do it in your component constructor. Each time you call `bind`, a new function is created. https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Answer (score 0):

1) put your babel config into a `.babelrc` file instead of the webpack config

2) add the `babel-jest` package to your project:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
```

3) add a transformer to your `jest.config.js`:

```
'transform': {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
}
```